# Text property overriden

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a textbox and a linkbutton within the EditItemTemplate of my ListView:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_notes" runat="server" Placeholder='<%# Eval("notes") %>'></asp:TextBox>
<asp:LinkButton ID="btn_update" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" OnClick="btn_update_Click" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("carID") %>' runat="server" >Update</asp:LinkButton>
```

I have this code:

```
protected void btn_update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var btn_update = (LinkButton)sender;
    int ID = System.Convert.ToInt32(btn_update.CommandArgument);
    TextBox txt_notes = (TextBox)listview.EditItem.FindControl("txt_notes");
    string notes = txt_notes.Text;
}
```

Now when I set a break point at `string notes = txt_notes.Text` it says the txt_notes.Text has nothing in it even though I have typed something in the textbox, so it seems that it is being overridden by the ItemDataBound or the PageLoad.

Does anyone know how I should overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are binding your listview on page load but not checking if it is on a postback. try the below

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        listview.DataSource = your_data_source;
        listview.DataBind();
     }
}
```